# How to populate MySQL tables for Spring Security Role Based Access Authorization using RESTful?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I have 3 MySQL tables and I'm using them for Spring Security configuration with roles. And I want to populate 2 of them using RESTful.

User table:
[image]

Role table:
[image]

User_role table (this is the join table):
[image]

The app works successfully but at this moment I populate these tables from MySQL Workbench and I want to populate them using RESTful. But I don't know exactly how to do that, how the JSON object should look like when I do the POST request? For example the role table will be by default with these 2 values: ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER, so I don't want to add any new value at this table, but how do I add a new user and populate the user table and the user_role table?

These are the entities:

User entity:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name = "appuser")
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, 
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "appuser_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appuser_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "approle_id"))
    private List<Role> authorities;

    public ApplicationUser() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Role> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Role> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

}
```

Role entity:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "approle")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String authority;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private Set<ApplicationUser> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Role() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public Set<ApplicationUser> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<ApplicationUser> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return authority;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. What is your goal or requirement?  Is just a proof of concept?